# what we can use for JedisExhaustedPoolException in jedis 4.0.1 since its deprecated

Tags: redis, jedis

I am using version of  3.8.0 Jedis and i am making use of one of the exceptions

```
import redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisExhaustedPoolException;

public Jedis getJedisObj() {
    try {
        return jedisPool.getResource();
    } catch (JedisConnectionException npe) {
        LOGGER.error("Not able to get redis connection {}", npe);
    } catch (JedisExhaustedPoolException npe) {
        LOGGER.error("Not able to get redis connection, because of pool exhausted {}", npe);
    }
    return null;
}
```

i want to upgrade to jedis 4.0.1 .Since this  redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisExhaustedPoolException is depreacted in 4.0.1 what can i use to replace that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisException`.

From [Jedis 3 to 4 doc](https://github.com/redis/jedis/blob/master/docs/3to4.md):

> `JedisExhaustedPoolException` has been removed. A `JedisException` with a similar message is thrown instead.